# Why does this Java code create a stack overflow error?

Tags: java

The code below produces a stack over flow error when it is executed. However If remove either of

- `static final GenerateStackOverflow E1 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value1");`
- `final GenerateStackOverflow E2 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value2");`

It runs without a stack over flow error. How come I get a stack overflow error if I have the above two lines but no error if only one of the lines is in the class?

```
public class GenerateStackOverflow {

    private final String value; 

    static final GenerateStackOverflow E1 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value1");
    final GenerateStackOverflow E2 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value2");


    public GenerateStackOverflow(String value) {
        System.out.println("GenerateStackOverflow.GenerateStackOverflow()");
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenerateStackOverflow.class.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because each instance of the object class a new instance of the class.  Which creates a new instance of the class, which creates a new instance of the class....

Comment: You are creating an infinitely long linked list of instances (through the `E2` reference).

Comment: The object is instantiating itselfs when its instantiating ...

Comment: You only get the error with both lines because no instance of the class is created without the first, and there's no recursion without the second.

Comment: Not sure why this received a downvote.  Interesting example.

Comment: @KevinBowersox - I don't see why you think it's "interesting" -- it simple infinite recursion, nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are needed to generate a `StackOverflowError`.  When you include this line:

```
static final GenerateStackOverflow E1 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value1");
```

An instance of `GenerateStackOverflow` is created when the class if first accessed.

Without this line included:

```
final GenerateStackOverflow E2 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value2");
```

things are fine.  But this line is critical.  Each time an instance of `GenerateStackOverflow` is created, it attempts to initialize its member variable `E2` -- another `GenerateStackOverflow` object.  Then *that* instance will have *its* `E2` initialized to another `GenerateStackOverflow` object.  This continues until a `StackOverflowError` occurs.

If the second line is included but the first isn't, then no instance is created and the infinite recursion is never entered.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor calls itself :

```
final GenerateStackOverflow E2 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value2");
```

So, to construct an instance, you need to construct an instance, which needs to construct an instance, etc.

Your programs's main method loads the class. And there is a static field which calls the constructor of the class, which creates the stack overflow. So removing the static variable hides the problem because the constructor is never called. And removing the non-static variable removes the recursive call completely, which fixes the probem.

Answer (score 1):

The `static final` line means a `GenerateStackOverflow` is instantiated every time the class is loaded; that's just once. The `final` line means one is instantiated every time the class is instantiated.

Your `main` method loads the class but does not instantiate it. So:

- With the `static final` line only, loading the class instantiates a `GenerateStackOverflow` and that's it
- With the `final` line only, loading the class doesn't do anything further
- With both, loading the class instantiates a `GenerateStackOverflow` (due to the `static` line), which then instantiates another `GenerateStackOverflow` (due to the non-`static` line), which then instantiates *another* `GenerateStackOverflow`, and so on until you get the stack overflow.

If your `main` method had instead been:

```
new GenerateStackOverflow("boom");
```

... then just the non-`static` line would be enough to cause the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

*Recursive constructor call* is the simple answer.

### Trick

Used `static final` for variable so that constructor is called and that constructor inturn tries to create an instance of itself using the `final` variable, which results in Recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the infinite loop without either field:

```
public class GenerateStackOverflow {

    private final String value; 

    static {
        GenerateStackOverflow E1 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value1");
    }

    public GenerateStackOverflow(String value) {
        System.out.println("GenerateStackOverflow.GenerateStackOverflow()");
        GenerateStackOverflow E2 = new GenerateStackOverflow("value2");
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenerateStackOverflow.class.getName();
    }
}
```

It's not the final fields that produce the loop, it's the `new` operations.

You could also get the error by removing the `static` clause and inserting a `new GenerateStackOverflow(...)` call in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example can, while still showing similar behavior, be reduced to this:

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo T1 = new Foo();
    Foo T2 = new Foo();

    Foo() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

T2 will get assigned when an instance is created, which means that the code can be refactored to this:

```
public class Foo {
    static Foo T1 = new Foo();
    Foo T2;

    Foo() {
        T2 = new Foo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

This second form makes it quite obvious that the constructor is calling itself. So why does removing T1 or T2 also remove the StackOverflowError?

- When the line with T1 is removed, then the main method will run but
  the class is never instantiated. (Calling Foo.class.getName() does not call the constructor.)
- When T2 is removed, then the constructor will no longer call itself, and the source of the StackOverflowError is removed.