# My Object[] Array is crashing out my program. I am doing something very wrong

Tags: java, arrays, object

So. I am trying to create an object array in my superclass.. lets use a common example: cars.

I have my array initialized: `Car[] cars = { new Car("Ford", "Sedan", "Focus", 17950) };`

However, this data is crashing my program. I have been researching this for hours and I cannot find a solution. Either I am not phrasing it correctly, or I am just not looking hard enough.

Here is the pastebin example of the code:
https://pastebin.com/uE2wtL4R

```
public class Car {
    // Data
    protected String cMan, vType, name; // in order, car manufacturer, sedan, suv, name
    protected double price;

    // constructor
    Car(String cMan, String vType, String name, double price) {
        this.cMan = cMan;
        this.vType = vType;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    Car[] cars = { new Car("Ford", "Sedan", "Focus", 17950) };
}
```

Comment: Your `cars` field is an *instance* field, which means a new one is constructed for every `Car` instance. Since the `cars` field initializer itself constructs a new `Car` instance, you get unbounded recursion. The solution is to make the `cars` field `static` (or put it in a different class).

Comment: Problem is explained here [Why does this Java code create a stack overflow error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18542308) but to suggest correct solution we need to know what you *want* your application to do.

Comment: As an aside: if your code throws some `Exception`, you should always include the stack trace and highlight the line(s), that causes the exception.

Comment: I think it's creating a memory leak of sorts.. meaning it runs, but it like a fork bomb in the sense I have to terminate it due to lag or some strange occurrence.

Comment: No. It is just an endless recursion, flooding the stack memory, which ultimately leads to an `StackOverflowException` and the (abnormal) termination of the program. Although not impossible, it is quite complicated to create a true memory leak in Java.

Answer (score -3):

That's not a valid location to put this line:

```
Car[] cars = {new Car("Ford", "Sedan", "Focus", 17950)};
```

That needs to be inside a method body (such as in your `main` method)

Comment: It's not wrong to have that line at the top-level of a class; it's a valid field declaration and initialization. (It's wrong to have it in the top-level of the `Car` class, but that's for a different reason.)

Comment: So basically I cannot hide the array in the superclass? I have to keep it in main?